# springboot 2.7.x ExceptionHandler returns double JSON data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm using springboot version 2.7.11

### IndexController.java

```java
package com.system.controller;

import cn.hutool.core.map.MapUtil;
import com.google.code.kaptcha.Producer;
import com.system.common.Result;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class IndexController {
    @Autowired
    private Producer producer;

    @GetMapping("/captcha")
    public Result captcha() throws IOException {
        //generate captcha characters
        String code = producer.createText();
        //generate a uuid (a string of random characters) as the key, b7af2ad9-4be8-49dc-b0fa9b4707ddd7b3.
        //generate a captcha, store it in the redis database, uuid as the storage key, and the captcha is the value corresponding to the storage key
        String key = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        //convert the generated captcha to an image, image is an image object in memory
        BufferedImage image = producer.createImage(code);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", out);
        //Base64 encoding
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        String str = "data:image/jpeg;base64,";
        String base64Image = str + encoder.encode(out.toByteArray());
        //Output the log on the server side, what is the captcha and the random code of the storage redis key
        log.info("captcha--{}--{}", key, code);
        //The location where the exception was thrown, which is the correct code:
        //MapUtil.builder().put("key", key).put("captchaImg", base64Image).build());
        // The builder() method is missing                        
        return Result.success(
                MapUtil.builder().put("key", key).put("captchaImg", base64Image));
        //return Result.success(MakeMistake());
    }

    private String MakeMistake() {
        throw new NullPointerException("Array null");
       //return "mistake";
    }
}
```

### KaptchConfig.java

```java
package com.system.config;

import com.google.code.kaptcha.Constants;
import com.google.code.kaptcha.impl.DefaultKaptcha;
import com.google.code.kaptcha.util.Config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.Properties;
@Configuration
public class KaptchConfig {
    @Bean
    public DefaultKaptcha producer() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        //If there is a border, the default is true,  can set yes, no
        properties.setProperty(Constants.KAPTCHA_BORDER, "no");
        // The default Color for CAPTCHA text characters is color.black
        properties.setProperty(Constants.KAPTCHA_TEXTPRODUCER_FONT_COLOR,
                "blue");
        // The default spacing for CAPTCHA text characters is 2
        properties.setProperty(Constants.KAPTCHA_TEXTPRODUCER_CHAR_SPACE,
                "4");
        // By default, the height of the CAPTCHA image is 50
        properties.setProperty(Constants.KAPTCHA_IMAGE_HEIGHT, "40");
        // By default, the CAPTCHA image width is 200
        properties.setProperty(Constants.KAPTCHA_IMAGE_WIDTH, "120");
        // The default CAPTCHA text character size is 40
        properties.setProperty(Constants.KAPTCHA_TEXTPRODUCER_FONT_SIZE,
                "30");
        Config config = new Config(properties);
        DefaultKaptcha defaultKaptcha = new DefaultKaptcha();
        defaultKaptcha.setConfig(config);
        return defaultKaptcha;
    }
}
```

### GlobalException.java

```java
package com.system.common.exception;

import com.system.common.Result;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;

@Slf4j
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalException {
//    AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException;
    @ExceptionHandler(value = AccessDeniedException.class)
    public Result handler(AccessDeniedException e){
        log.info("spring security permission denied---{}",e.getMessage());
        return Result.fail("permission denied");
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(value = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public Result handler(IllegalArgumentException e){
        log.info("spring security Argument error---{}",e.getMessage());
        return Result.fail("Argument error");
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = RuntimeException.class)
    public Result handler(RuntimeException e){
        log.info("RuntimeException---{}",e.getMessage());
        return Result.fail("RuntimeException"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I remove the.build() method from the IndexController.java file, I write it directly into the parameters and then return two json data. What is the cause of this problem and how can I avoid it? demoted to 2.3.12.RELEASE and the error disappears.
[image]
Help is greatly appreciated

This is the code where the problem occurs：
[why-i-get-double-json](https://github.com/HanHan666666/why-i-get-double-json)